# Does “M&M rule” applies to std::atomic data-member?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, atomic, mutable

*"Mutable is used to specify that the member does not affect the externally visible state of the class (as often used for **mutexes**, memo caches, lazy evaluation, and access instrumentation)."* [Reference: [cv (const and volatile) type qualifiers, mutable specifier]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv#:%7E:text=The%20%22M%26M%20rule%22%3A%20mutable%20and%20mutex%20go%20together)

This sentence made me wonder:

*"Guideline: Remember the “M&M rule”: **For a member-variable, mutable and mutex (**or atomic**) go together**."* [Reference: [GotW #6a Solution: Const-Correctness, Part 1 (updated for C ++11/14)]](https://isocpp.org/blog/2013/05/gotw-6a-solution-overriding-virtual-functions-herb-sutter#:%7E:text=Guideline%3A%20Remember%20the%20%E2%80%9CM%26M%20rule%E2%80%9D%3A%20For%20a%20member%20variable%2C%20mutable%20and%20mutex%20(or%20atomic)%20go%20together.)

I understand why “M&M rule” applies to `std::mutex` data-member: to allow **const**-functions to be thread-safe despite they lock/unlock the mutex data-member, but does “M&M rule”  applies also to `std::atomic` data-member?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got it partly backwards. The article does not suggest to make all atomic members mutable. Instead it says:

> (1) For a member variable, mutable implies mutex (or equivalent): A
> mutable member variable is presumed to be a mutable shared variable
> and so must be synchronized internally—protected with a mutex, made
> atomic, or similar.
>
> (2) For a member variable, mutex (or similar synchronization type)
> implies mutable: A member variable that is itself of a synchronization
> type, such as a mutex or a condition variable, naturally wants to be
> mutable, because you will want to use it in a non-const way (e.g.,
> take a std::lock_guard) inside concurrent const member
> functions.

(2) says that you want a mutex member mutable. Because typically you also want to lock the mutex in `const` methods. (2) does not mention atomic members.

(1) on the other hand says that if a member is mutable, then you need to take care of synchronization internally, be it via a mutex or by making the member an `atomic`. That is because of the bullets the article mentions before:

> If you are implementing a type, unless you know objects of the type can never be shared (which is generally impossible), this means that each of your const member functions must be either:
>
> - truly physically/bitwise const with respect to this object, meaning that they perform no writes to the object’s data; or else
> - internally synchronized so that if it does perform any actual writes to the object’s data, that data is correctly protected with a mutex or equivalent (or if appropriate are atomic<>) so that any possible concurrent const accesses by multiple callers can’t tell the difference.

A member that is mutable is not "truly const", hence you need to take care of synchronization internally (either via a mutex or by making the member atomic).

TL;DR: The article does not suggest to make all atomic members mutable. It rather suggests to make mutex members mutable and to use internal synchronization for all mutable members.